# How to create a list of usernames based on a specific requirement? (Android Studio - Azure)

Tags: list, azure, android-studio, arraylist

I need help with a project I'm doing. I tried to create a list of the `Usernames` of the users which their "`Type`" is "`Trainer`" (view the attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6EOh.png), please)

---

I tried using this code:

```
List<users>results=mMyTable.where().field("type").eq(trainer).execute().get();
        List<String> TrainersList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<results.size();i++)
        {
          TrainersList.add(results.get(i).getUsername().toString());
        }
```

But it doesn't work and I can't understand why.

I would really appreciate help with this one

The error message is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.query.ExecutableQuery com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.table.MobileServiceTable.where()' on a null object reference

Comment: try to use "TYPE" instead of "type" . and also write trainer in quotes . "trainer"

Comment: On the azure table it shows everything with capital letters but if I'll press "Manage Schema" you'll see I wrote it down with lowercase ones.
Thanks for the comment :)